# How do I change the table schema with SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some code which defines and creates SQL database tables using the SQL Alchemy declarative style.

The reference for the declarative style can be found [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#accessing-table-and-metadata).

Tables are created with this code:

```
engine = create_engine(db_url)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

`Base` inherits from `DeclarativeBase`, you can find an example of how to use this to define the tables to be created on the same [documentation page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column).

For convenience, here is that example:

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    fullname = mapped_column(String)
    nickname = mapped_column(String(30))
```

If I run the code to create this table, when connected to Postgres, the tables are created in the default "public" table namespace.

How can I change this so that I can control which schema the tables to be created are associated with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another attribute `__table_args__` where additional metadata can be associated with a table type.

Here is how to use it to define the `schema` parameter:

```
__tablename__ = 'your_table_name'
__table_args__ = {'schema': 'your_schema_name'}
```

With this, the table schema can be set, for databases which have support for this.

I don't know what it does for databases which do not support schemas, or use schemas in a conceptually different way from "namespaces". (eg: Oracle)